# Is there a better algorithm to assign numbers to combinations?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, combinations, combinatorics

It is well known that Pascal's identity can be used to encode a combination of *k* elements out of *n* into a number from 0 to `(n \choose k) - 1` (let's call this number a *combination index*) using a [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). Assuming constant time for arithmetic operations, this algorithm takes O(*n*) time.<sup>†</sup>

I have an application where *k* ≪ *n* and an algorithm in O(*n*) time is infeasible. Is there an algorithm to bijectively assign a number between 0 and  `(n \choose k) - 1` to a combination of *k* elements out of *n* whose runtime is of order O(*k*) or similar? The algorithm does not need to compute the same mapping as the combinatorial number system, however, the inverse needs to be computable in a similar time complexity.

---

† More specifically, the algorithm computing the combination from the combination index runs in O(*n*) time. Computing the combination index from the combination works in O(*k*) time if you pre-compute the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Do you have to map this specifically to a number between the "dense" range between 0 and (n \choose k) - 1? If you could relax this to a sparser range, it would be easy to come up with something w(n).

Comment: @AmiTavory The map must be dense for my purpose.

Comment: What about preprocessing? If OK, what would be the time/space constraints?

Comment: @AmiTavory The input is a number *k* and an (optionally sorted) array of *k* different numbers from 0 to *n* &minus; 1. You may use precomputed tabled of reasonable size (say, O(*n*) but don't feel constrainted by that) and however much space you like.

Comment: The Wikipedia page's algorithm to turn a number N into its corresponding k-combination can be implemented to take O(klog n) time if you use binary search to find each c_k.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I thought of binary search too for that, but the formula requires not only finding the order of the elements, but actually computing combinatorial terms involving them. I don't see how these computations are constant time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Indeed. Good point. I didn't consider this.

Comment: @AmiTavory Well, you could use a pre-computed look-up table for the coefficients.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Hence my question about preprocessing constraints - the size of the lookup table is basically n, no?

Comment: @AmiTavory: I think the lookup table will have to have nk elements, but maybe there's an optimisation I'm missing.  That might be too big to be feasible, but you can reduce space requirements by any factor b if you're prepared to increase times by the same factor: just store every b-th value.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're right.

Comment: Max c_k, so that c_k choose k < N => c_k ~ (N * k!)^(1/k) + k/2.

Answer (score 1):

Description of a comment.

For given combinatorial index (`N`), to find `k'th` digit it is needed to find `c_k` such that `(c_k \choose k) <= N` and `((c_k+1) \choose k) > N`.

Set `P(i,k) = i!/(i-k)!`.

```
P(i, k) = i * (i-1) * ... * (i-k+1)
substitute x = i - (k-1)/2
  = (x+(k-1)/2) * (x+(k-1)/2-1) * ... * (x-(k-1)/2+1) * (x-(k-1)/2)
  = (x^2 - ((k-1)/2)^2) * (x^2 - ((k-1)/2-1)^2) * ...
  = x^k - sum(((k-2i-1)/2)^2))*x^(k-2) + O(x^(k-4))
  = x^k - O(x^(k-2))
P(i, k) = (i - (k-1)/2)^k - O(i^(k-2))
```

From above inequality:

```
(c_k \choose k) <= N
P(c_k, k) <= N * k!
c_k ~= (N * k!)^(1/k) + (k-1)/2
```

I am not sure how large is O(c_k^(k-2)) part. I suppose it doesn't influence too much. If it is of order `(c_k+1)/(c_k-k+1)` than approximation is very good. That is due:

```
((c_k+1) \choose k) = (c_k \choose k) * (c_k + 1) / (c_k - k + 1)
```

I would try algorithm something like:

```
For given k
Precalculate k!

For given N
For i in (k, ..., 0)
  Calculate c_i with (N * i!)^(1/i) + (i-1)/2
  (*) Check is P(c_i, k) <=> N * i!
    If smaller check c_i+1
    If larger check c_i-1
    Repeat (*) until found P(c_i, i) <= N * i! < P(c_i+1, i)
  N = N - P(c_i, i)
```

If approximation is good, `number of steps << k`, than finding one digit is O(k).